# Seeking a good solution for SVG + Javascript framework

Tags: javascript, frameworks, svg

I'm looking to hear others experiences with SVG + Javascript Frameworks.

Things that I'd like the framework to handle - DOM creation, event handling and minimal size.

Jquery SVG plugin - http://keith-wood.name/svg.html seems to be the only one I can find.

Answer (score 17):

[Raphael](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) is a javascript framework for manipulating vector graphics, either with SVG or VML, depending on what the browser supports.

Answer (score 4):

Check the [D3 library](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)

> D3.js is a small, free JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite JavaScript framework is jQuery. But original jQuery package is unable to run inside SVG because of some HTML-specific places.

But I have patched the newest version of jQuery (1.4.2) so it is able to run under SVG now. You can take [patched jQuery package from here](http://hgcoaxial.appspot.com/static/jquery-1.4.2.svg.js).

A single issue with it is that SVG doesn't invoke initialization function from incuded jQuery source so I was to introduce `jQueryInitialize` function and `jQueryInitialize(window);` must be invoked manually in `svg:onload` event.

Answer (score 2):

This post is too old but I think maybe people will be interesting checking out [`http://snapsvg.io/`](http://snapsvg.io/) which is a framework build by the same guy that did Raphael. But for modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need SVG or just vector-like graphics manipulation?  John Resig ported the "Processing" visualization language to JavaScript.  I never used it, but from the creator of jQuery it may help you out if you don't actually require SVG.

http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet, but i bookmarked [PlotKit](http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/) some time ago because it's a javascript framework that generates svg

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but spam prevention mechanism impede me from posting more than one hyperlink in one answer. [Here is prove of concept of running jQuery under SVG](http://hgcoaxial.appspot.com/test).